# My Home address will change during ESTA period, is it affected?

Tags: usa, esta

My ESTA is in its second year. My lease is up on my UK address and I will change addresses in the next few weeks. I am flying to the US on March 1st for another visit. Will my address change affect my ESTA or my 90 day allowance?

Answer (score 1):

No, a change in your residential address won't affect your ESTA or your eligibility in the Visa Waiver Program.

Once your ESTA has been approved, it is valid until the expiry date of the ESTA.

Your ESTA is tied to the passport details you submitted when applying for your initial ESTA. If your passport has changed (new passport number, expiry date etc) then you'd need to re-apply for a new ESTA.

Source: I've personally moved houses (and countries) and traveled with the same ESTA. There is some coverage about when you need to change / re-apply for an ESTA here: https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/1073/~/apply-or-change-information-in-the-electronic-system-for-travel-authorization